# Smooth a curve in Python while preserving the value and slope at the end points

Tags: python, filtering, signal-processing, spline, smoothing

I have two solutions to this problem actually, they are both applied below to a test case. The thing is that none of them is perfect: first one only take into account the two end points, the other one can't be made "arbitrarily smooth": there is a limit in the amount of smoothness one can achieve (the one I am showing).
I am sure there is a better solution, that kind-of go from the first solution to the other and all the way to no smoothing at all. It may already be implemented somewhere. Maybe solving a minimization problem with an arbitrary number of splines equidistributed?

Thank you very much for your help

Ps: the seed used is a challenging one

[image: Example of filtering]

```py
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from scipy import interpolate
    from scipy.signal import savgol_filter
    import numpy as np 
    import random

    def scipy_bspline(cv, n=100, degree=3):
        """ Calculate n samples on a bspline
            cv :      Array ov control vertices
            n  :      Number of samples to return
            degree:   Curve degree
        """
        cv = np.asarray(cv)
        count = cv.shape[0]
        degree = np.clip(degree,1,count-1)
        kv = np.clip(np.arange(count+degree+1)-degree,0,count-degree)
    
        # Return samples
        max_param = count - (degree * (1-periodic))
        spl = interpolate.BSpline(kv, cv, degree)
        return spl(np.linspace(0,max_param,n))

    def round_up_to_odd(f):
        return np.int(np.ceil(f / 2.) * 2 + 1)
    
    def generateRandomSignal(n=1000, seed=None):
        """
        Parameters
        ----------
        n : integer, optional
            Number of points in the signal. The default is 1000.
    
        Returns
        -------
        sig : numpy array
    
        """
        np.random.seed(seed)
        print("Seed was:", seed)
        steps = np.random.choice(a=[-1, 0, 1], size=(n-1))
        roughSig = np.concatenate([np.array([0]), steps]).cumsum(0)
        sig = savgol_filter(roughSig, round_up_to_odd(n/10), 6)
        return sig
    
    # Generate a random signal to illustrate my point
    n = 1000
    t = np.linspace(0, 10, n)
    seed = 45136. # Challenging seed
    sig = generateRandomSignal(n=1000, seed=seed)
    sigInit = np.copy(sig)
    
    # Add noise to the signal
    mean = 0
    std = sig.max()/3.0
    num_samples = n/5
    idxMin = n/2-100
    idxMax = idxMin + num_samples
    tCut = t[idxMin+1:idxMax]
    noise = np.random.normal(mean, std, size=num_samples-1) + 2*std*np.sin(2.0*np.pi*tCut/0.4)
    sig[idxMin+1:idxMax] += noise
    
    # Define filtering range enclosing the noisy area of the signal
    idxMin -= 20
    idxMax += 20
    
    # Extreme filtering solution
    # Spline between first and last points, the points in between have no influence
    sigTrim = np.delete(sig, np.arange(idxMin,idxMax))
    tTrim = np.delete(t, np.arange(idxMin,idxMax))
    f = interpolate.interp1d(tTrim, sigTrim, kind='quadratic')
    sigSmooth1 = f(t)
    
    # My attempt. Not bad but not perfect because there is a limit in the maximum
    # amount of smoothing we can add (degree=len(tSlice) is the maximum)
    # If I could do degree=10*len(tSlice) and converging to the first solution
    # I would be done!
    sigSlice = sig[idxMin:idxMax]
    tSlice = t[idxMin:idxMax]
    cv = np.stack((tSlice, sigSlice)).T
    p = scipy_bspline(cv, n=len(tSlice), degree=len(tSlice))
    tSlice = p.T[0]
    sigSliceSmooth = p.T[1]
    sigSmooth2 = np.copy(sig)
    sigSmooth2[idxMin:idxMax] = sigSliceSmooth
    
    # Plot
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(t, sig, label="Signal")
    plt.plot(t, sigSmooth1, label="Solution 1")
    plt.plot(t, sigSmooth2, label="Solution 2")
    plt.plot(t[idxMin:idxMax], sigInit[idxMin:idxMax], label="What I'd want (kind of, smoother will be even better actually)")
    plt.plot([t[idxMin],t[idxMax]], [sig[idxMin],sig[idxMax]],"o")
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
    sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a minimization is a good way to approach this smoothing problem.

#### Least squares problem

Here is a suggestion for a least squares formulation: let s[0], ..., s[N] denote the N+1 samples of the given signal to smooth, and let L and R be the desired slopes to preserve at the left and right endpoints. Find the smoothed signal u[0], ..., u[N] as the minimizer of

min_u (1/2) sum_n (u[n] - s[n])² + (λ/2) sum_n (u[n+1] - 2 u[n] + u[n-1])²

subject to 
s[0] = u[0], s[N] = u[N] (value constraints), 
L = u[1] - u[0], R = u[N] - u[N-1] (slope constraints),

where in the minimization objective, the sums are over n = 1, ..., N-1 and λ is a positive parameter controlling the smoothing strength. The first term tries to keep the solution close to the original signal, and the second term penalizes u for bending to encourage a smooth solution.

The slope constraints require that
u[1] = L + u[0] = L + s[0] and u[N-1] = u[N] - R = s[N] - R. So we can consider the minimization as over only the interior samples u[2], ..., u[N-2].

#### Finding the minimizer

The minimizer satisfies the Euler–Lagrange equations

(u[n] - s[n]) / λ + (u[n+2] - 4 u[n+1] + 6 u[n] - 4 u[n-1] + u[n-2]) = 0 
for n = 2, ..., N-2.

An easy way to find an approximate solution is by gradient descent: initialize `u = np.copy(s)`, set u[1] = L + s[0] and u[N-1] = s[N] - R, and do 100 iterations or so of

```
u[2:-2] -= (0.05 / λ) * (u - s)[2:-2] + np.convolve(u, [1, -4, 6, -4, 1])[4:-4]
```

But with some more work, it is possible to do better than this by solving the E–L equations directly. For each n, move the known quantities to the right-hand side: s[n] and also the endpoints u[0] = s[0], u[1] = L + s[0], u[N-1] = s[N] - R, u[N] = s[N]. The you will have a linear system "A u = b", and matrix A has rows like

0, ..., 0, 1, -4, (6 + 1/λ), -4, 1, 0, ..., 0.

Finally, solve the linear system to find the smoothed signal u. You could use `numpy.linalg.solve` to do this if N is not too large, or if N is large, try an iterative method like conjugate gradients.

Comment: Thank you very much for this really good answer! I am working on it.

Answer (score 0):

you can apply a simple smoothing method and plot the smooth curves with different smoothness values to see which one works best.

```
def smoothing(data, smoothness=0.5):
    last = data[0]
    new_data = [data[0]]
    for datum in data[1:]:
        new_value = smoothness * last + (1 - smoothness) * datum
        new_data.append(new_value)
        last = datum
    return new_data
```

You can plot this curve for multiple values of smoothness and pick the curve which suits your needs. You can also apply this method only on a range of values in the actual curve by defining start and end

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I just tested it and it doesn't seem to do the trick. smoothness = 0 -> the two curves are equal, smoothness = 1 -> the two curves are almost equal (a bit shifted actually). Maybe I am missing something?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_smoothing I think this might help you...